# What effect did the duration of Mongol presence in Galicia-Volhynia versus Vladimir-Suzdal have on the development of modern day Ukraine and Russia?

Tags: russia, mongol-empire, ukraine, russian-empire

In [Serhii Plokhy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serhii_Plokhy)'s book "[The Gates of Europe - a History of Ukraine](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25255053-the-gates-of-europe)" the author states that the arrival of the Mongols ended the rule of Kyivan-Rus and effectively split the Kyivan realm into the principalities of Vladimir-Suzdal in today's Russia and Galicia-Volhynia in central and western-Ukraine. The author goes on to further state:

> In the lands of what is now Russia, ruled from Vladimir, the Mongol presence lasted until the end of the fifteenth century and eventually became known as the “Tatar yoke,”

> In Ukraine, ruled by the Galician and Volhynian princes, the Mongols were less intrusive and oppressive than they were in Russia. Their rule was also of shorter duration, effectively over by the mid-fourteenth century.

What effect did this difference in duration under Mongol rule for the two principalities of Galicia-Volhynia and Vladimir-Suzdal have on the development of what later became modern day Ukraine and Russia?

edit - the author states that this discrepency in the time under which these two provinces were under Mongol rule had "a profound effect" on the development of the two nations but as specifically for what effect the Mongol occupations had on the two I feel he doesn't discuss in much depth and this statement is left hanging in the air a little bit. The successive chapters are devoted mainly to how the Polish-Lithuanian common wealth influenced the development of Ukraine. I wondered if this extra century of life under the Mongols in the case of Vladimir-Suzdal might explain in any way the imperialistic path which Muscovy/Russia chose to take?

Comment: I am not a specialist, but I would say it had few influence on the development (in the meaning of economics, buildings, technics...) because Mongol rulers did not control these domains. Moreover, the most difference of paths for these provinces is the intrusion of Poland Lithuania

Comment: There is definitely a cultural difference between the two areas though (well, I guess a lot of Russian Nationalists would not agree...), and this is pretty much where the split happened.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Among other benefits, it clarifies that the scope on this question is actually rather narrow (at least in terms of time).